# Order by not working in SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to query by Discharge__c (custom object) record with the most recent discharge_date__c.

This is the query I am using:

```
Discharge__c dis = [select id, name_dob_formula__c, date_of_birth__c, discharge_date__c from discharge__c where Name_DOB_formula__c =: namePlusDob order by discharge_date__c desc limit 1];
```

However it does not seem to be working. It is querying old discharge__c records with later discharge_date__c's  Is there something I should change in the query?

Comment: What are some of the values of `discharge_date__c` being returned, in order? What happens if you remove `limit 1`? Did you consider adding `NULLS LAST` to your query?

Comment: Thank you-- this debugging helped me solve the issue. Actually the query was working ok, but the issue was with my Name_DOB_formula__c  field. Appreciate the assistance